# How to use jQuery Split with 2 Arguments?

Tags: jquery, regex, split

I am wondering how to use `jQuery.Split()` with an "OR" - i.e. like

`example@example.com, example2@example.com,example3@example.com`

So it returns like

```
example@example.com
example2@example.com
example3@example.com
```

But notice the `",<space>"` and `","` - that is - I want to split this string using EITHER `","` or `",<space>"` ?

Comment: On a side not, `split()` is a javascript method, nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no jQuery split ..

Just use a regular expression..

```
var str = 'example@example.com, example2@example.com,example3@example.com';
var list = str.split(/,[ ]{0,}/);
```

or as @Andomar mentions in the comments, the simpler

```
var list = str.split(/,\s*/);
```

Comment: +1 No need for a character class for a single character, and  you could use `*` as shorthand for `{0,}` (f.e. `/,\s*/`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions-

```
.split(new RegExp(pattern));
```

or in your case, probably I haven't checked this and am relatively new to regex. \s denotes whitespace

```
.split(new RegExp('(\s*,\s*)'));
```